# Categories on Wordpress stopped working

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, categories

I built a custom Wordpress theme and had tested it out on my server as a demo for my client. Everything worked smoothly on the Browse page. If you clicked a category, it showed you the posts that correspond to the category.

Here is the test page I uploaded to my hosting account (Bluehost): 
http://greyepk.com/ilovedocs2/browse/

I've since migrated the site to my client's private server and now the categories page is no longer working.

Here is the broken page: http://syndicado.com/ilovedocs2/browse/

I've tried to reset the permalinks and the .htaccess file to no avail.

Below is the code from my .htaccess page:

```
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /ilovedocs2/
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /ilovedocs2/index.php [L]
    </IfModule>
```

I used Velvet Blues to adjust the links after migrating the site to the new server, but have since disabled the plugin. I don't have any other permalink plugins installed on the site.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: I had a similar problem on my site having exported the WordPress posts from the development site and - I thought - imported them to the new site. In fact the import had silently failed and I discovered that I had to break up the import file into small chunks for it to work. I ran the import until it failed then noted what the last file copied had been, and removed the text in the import file down to the next `<item>` tag. I then resaved it and imported again until there was nothing left in the file. Something like this http://www.tjkelly.com/blog/wordpress-import-failed-how-to-fix-it/

Comment: If you re-save the paths in the General Settings/Read page again it should write its own `.htaccess` file - on a different site where nothing other than the home page would show results it turned out that mine was not on the webroot where it should have been. Yours might be located/or need to be located somewhere else.

Comment: Thanks, Steve! I'll give this a shot and will let you know if that works!

Comment: Does it work if you publish a new category (for the new category only)?

Comment: Did you try posting on http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/  ?

Comment: If you opt to export again from your WordPress development site using Tools/Export, then import to the production site using Tools/Import use Chrome - the import script failed for me in FireFox - in Chrome I at least got to see which posts had been imported and where it had stopped (so enabling me to work out which `<item></item>` blocks I could remove from the xml file in Notepad before saving it and re-running the import process).